# Why do I get a "You seem to be improving a post however, you made no changes" error when I try to remove duplicate content from a question?

Tags: discussion, support, edits

[Inserting and executing conditional javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610574/inserting-and-executing-conditional-javascript) has a duplicated paragraph:

> Working on a Mobile First design and want to conditional load and
>   execute some javascript based on the browser width.
>
> Looked around for conditional examples and this worked in my test:
>
> Working on a Mobile First design and want to conditional load and
>   execute some javascript based on the browser width.
>
> Looked around for conditional examples and this worked in my test:

I tried editing it to remove the problem, but I got a **"You seem to be improving a post however, you made no changes"** error message. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that someone made the same edit just before you did.  So when it did a diff, it found that the text resulting from your change was the same as the current edit.

Answer (score 6):

The question had a suggested edit on it that removed the duplicate paragraphs. I just approved the edit and it went through fine.

I'm not sure what happened exactly, but my best guess is that while you were editing the post, another user submitted the suggested edit so when you went to submit yours, it looks exactly the same as the yet-unapproved suggestion and resulted in the error you saw.

If that's the case, I'm not sure if it's a bug or by design.